# Image.alpha_composite() - ValueError: images do not match

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open(r"./img/color/color1.png")
img2 = Image.open(r"./img/glasses/G1.png")

intermeadiate = Image.alpha_composite(img1, img2)
```

File "C:\Users\fpm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3029, in alpha_composite
return im1._new(core.alpha_composite(im1.im, im2.im))
ValueError: images do not match

Comment: Your images need to be of the same shape for the alpha_composite function

Comment: Try adding output from `print(img1,img2)` after opening to see how they compare.

Comment: I have the same problem and th images are of the same size